# Wordpress use Oracle as database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, oracle

MYSql is the default database of Wordpress. I wonder if Wordpress supports Oracle to be its database?

A client of mine wants to use Wordpress for their site but they use Oracle as their database. I do not know if it is supported. And if yes, what efforts should I look upon? Are there codes that I need to change on WP for it to query Oracle queries, etc?

I haven't look up on the queries that WP does but if they use MYSql statements, then it will be a lot of pain to do recode.

Are there any plugins or simple setup tutorial to support Oracle?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I doubt that you can use Oracle with Wp without a MASSIVE code rewrite,if at all.

Comment: it COULD be done, but I'd question if it SHOULD be done. remind your client that Oracle owns MySQL.  So, you port it with a TON of work. WP issues a critical security update. Now what?